# how to update query in the mysql database

Tags: android, mysql

i am trying to update in mysql database with the following code 
when i am running the program i am getting the following error in console

---

**Error:**

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
server version for the right syntax to use near 
'SET AVG_COST = 100000 , RWDS_INCENT = 200 , OTH_EXPENSES = 10000 , 
TRAVELLING_EX' at line 1
```

**Code:**

```
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,"root","root");
        System.out.println("Remote DB connection established");
        PreparedStatement statement=con.prepareStatement("UPDATE TBL_MONTHLY_EXPENSES_DETAILS  " +
                "SET AVG_COST = "+AVG_COST+" ," +
                   " RWDS_INCENT = "+RWDS_INCENT +" ,"+
                   " OTH_EXPENSES = "+OTH_EXPENSES+" ,"+
                   " TRAVELLING_EXPENSES = "+TRAVELLING_EXPENSES+" ,"+
                   " CLIENT_VISITS = "+CLIENT_VISITS+" ,"+
                   " REV_RECD = "+REV_RECD+" "
                +" WHERE PJT_CODE = '"+PJT_CODE
                +"' AND PJT_MONTH = '"+PJT_MONTH
                +"' AND PJT_YEAR = '"+PJT_YEAR+"' "
                );
        statement.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably something wrong with `TRAVELLING_EXPENSES`. Check the value you're trying to update.

Comment: Also i want to know the query to insert the same values in the mysql database.

Comment: i want INSERT the same data in mysql as same as above(UPDATE query).what are the things to modify in update query?

Comment: Something line: `INSERT INTO TBL_MONTHLY_EXPENSES_DETAILS (AVG_COST, RWDS_INCENT) VALUES (1, 2)`.
Add more columns and values yourself, you should just follow this pattern.